# Go: Why does converting from a float64 to a float32 and back cause a change to the value?

Tags: go

Is there a way to handle this cast without altering the data?

```golang
f := float64(-3942.2)
fmt.Println(float64(float32(f))) // = -3942.199951171875
```

The only way to get `-3942.2` back is to recast it as a `float32`:

```golang
fmt.Println(float32(float64(float32(f)))) // = -3942.2
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ReIefOPEaoz

#### edit:

This isn't a formatting issue:

```golang
f := float64(-3942.2)
fmt.Println(f == float64(float32(f))) // false
```

#### edit2:

```golang
fmt.Println(f) // -3942.2
fmt.Println(float32(f) == float32(float64(float32(f)))) // true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`float32` has less precision than `float64`. Neither type can exactly represent the real number -3942.2, but `float64` gets closer.

When you convert to `float32`, the value must be rounded to the nearest value representable as a `float32`. The lost information cannot be recovered; casting back to `float64` will not reproduce the original value.

A third cast back to `float32`, as in `float32(float64(float32(f)))`, does not recover the original value. It only looks like it does because of the default rounding behavior of `fmt.Println`. By default, `fmt.Println` will print floating-point values with exactly enough digits to distinguish them from other values of the same type.

Because `float64` has more precision, the number of decimal digits required to distinguish `float64(float32(f))` from other `float64` values is greater than the number of decimal digits required to distinguish `float32(f)` or `float32(float64(float32(f)))` from other `float32` values.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same values, it's just default formatting of `fmt.Println` shows less significant digits for one but not for the other.

Compare with

https://play.golang.org/p/hJs-5Oz_YlL

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    f := float64(-3942.2)
    fmt.Printf("float64(float32(f)):\t\t%.20f\n", float64(float32(f)))

    fmt.Printf("float32(float64(float32(f))):\t%.20f\n", float32(float64(float32(f)))) // = -3942.2

}

// float64(float32(f)):     -3942.19995117187500000000
// float32(float64(float32(f))):    -3942.19995117187500000000
```

Comment: They aren't the same value

`fmt.Println(float64(float32(f)) == f) // false`

Comment: @Chance in your original post you never print value of f directly (without converting it once to float32) -3942.2 cannot be stored exactly in float32 neither in float64, but in float64 you will have a closer approximation (more digits), so this is why they are not equal.

Comment: @mgagnon https://play.golang.org/p/7q0Yq26OCBL

`fmt.Println(f) // -3942.2`

`fmt.Println(float32(f) == float32(float64(float32(f))))` // true

Comment: @Chance this is what I expect. Once converted in float32, it cannot get back the precision it lost.

Comment: @Chance my answer explained the difference in the output of the **original** question. And no, it makes no sense to compare `float64(float32(f)) == f`, because you lose precision. But after you lost it (like in the v1 of the question) - they are **the same values**. From the **original question**: `fmt.Println(float32(f) == float32(float64(float32(f)))) // true` (as expected)